# Is there any api available that can get contacts from my gmail account?

Tags: google-api, google-schemas

There are many  api's available e.g. for post the message, list profile, get threads but  I need the api to get the contacts from my account.

Answer (score 0):

Google Contacts API version 3.0 can do that.

Documentation Link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

What language do you use ?